# TkInter disable buttons while thread is running

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have an app that tries to generate text when a button is pressed. Most of the time the text generation is fast but there is one function that takes about 20 seconds to execute (depending on the amount of text). During that process the GUI used to freeze so I transferred that function on a separate thread and everything is fine on that field.

Now I have an issue with the buttons. When the function that takes some time to execute is running, the user can still click the button and that function will be executed several times while the first call is still being processed.
I would like to prevent that by disabling all the buttons while that function is running but I can't get the threading to work properly.

Here is the code that I have:

```
def generate_text():
    choice = dropdown_choice.get()
    if context_obj.context_text.get() == '':
        if choice == 'OpenAI':
            context = 'Some random context text'

        else:
            context = ' '
    else:
        context = context_obj.context_text.get()

    if choice == 'OpenAI':
        progress.start(50)
        progress_bar_text = Label(text='Please wait while the text is being generated',
                            background='#E5F2FF',
                            font=("Helvetica", 12))

        progress_bar_text.place(relx=.2, 
                            rely=.66, 
                            anchor="c")

         # multithreading for the OpenAI text generation
        q = queue.Queue()
        thread1 = Thread(target=openAI_generator.sample, args=[text_amount.get(), temperature.get(), context, q])
        thread1.start()

        def display_AI_text(q):
            openAI_text = q.get()
            generated_text.configure(state='normal')
            generated_text.delete(1.0,END)
            generated_text.insert(tk.END, openAI_text)
            generated_text.configure(state='disabled')

            progress.stop()
            progress_bar_text.place_forget()

        thread2 = Thread(target=display_AI_text, args=[q])
        thread2.start()
```

In this code, `thread1` is executing the function and the `thread2` is taking the input from that function and displaying it.

What I would like to do is, while `thread2` is being executed, all the buttons to be disabled and when the thread finishes, the buttons to become enabled again.

I have tried adding:

```
thread2 = Thread(target=display_AI_text, args=[q])
generate_button.config(state="disabled")
thread2.start()
```

and then:

```
thread2.join()
generate_button.config(state="normal")
```

but this code freezes the app. I assume that the main thread is waiting for `thread2` to finish and that is why it is not responding.

Does anyone know a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: There is probably  some scheduling function that you can use?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many GUIs you can't change GUI in thread - you have to do it in main process.

You can use queue to send information to main process which will update GUI.

In Tkinter you can use

```
root.after(time_in_milliseconds, function_name)
```

to run periodically function which can check message from this queue.

Or it can periodically check

```
thread2.is_alive()
```

instead of using `thread2.join()` because `is_alive()` doesn't block code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import time

def long_running_function():
    print('start sleep')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('end sleep')

def start_thread():
    global t
    global counter

    b['state'] = 'disable'
    counter = 0

    t = Thread(target=long_running_function)
    t.start()

    check_thread()
    # or check after 100ms
    # root.after(100, check_thread) 

def check_thread():
    global counter

    if not t.is_alive():
        b['state'] = 'normal'
        l['text'] = ''
    else:
        l['text'] = str(counter)
        counter += 0.1

        # check again after 100ms
        root.after(100, check_thread) 

#-----------------------------------------------------

# counter displayed when thread is running        
counter = 0

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(root)
l.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_thread)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```